# Excel - count multiple words per cell in a range of cells

Tags: excel-formula

I have some cells with multiple names in them as so:

[image: Names in an Excel table]

Names are not repeated in the same cell.

I have some more cells below where I need to count how many times each name appears in each column.  The names of the people counted above are to the right in one column, and the number of times each name appears should be calculated in the corresponding row of the next column.

[image: Names and the number of times the name appears]

For example, the cells that read 2 and 0 should read 4 and 4 (for the amount of times they appear in the previous image).

Here is an example of the desired result:

[image: result]

What formula should I use to accomplish this?

Comment: 1.Do you have a list of words/names beforehand? 2. Can a name appear twice or more in the same cell, and if so, how many times should it be counted?

Comment: I can make one if necessary.  I'll update the question with what I have below the cells.  The names should only appear once per cell, although each cell may have multiple different names in it.

Comment: When you say, "I need to count ... ", what do you mean? Do you need some sort of Excel-specific functionality, or do you just need to use that data somewhere else?

Comment: I just need the number of times that name appears below.  I don't have to keep these things in the same format but if I could that would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array formula (Ctrl+Shift+Enter) for this. Set up your list of names somwhere (For example, F1, F2, F3 ...) then next to it (in G1):

```
 {=COUNT(IFERROR(FIND(F1,A:A,1),FALSE))}
```

Assuming A is you names column. Than simply drag G1 down to copy for all names.

Comment: When I put that into Excel it didn't read it as a formula until I removed the curly braces.  Am I supposed to do that?  Also, no matter what the formula always seems to evaluate as one.

Comment: the curly brackets are "Array Formula". when you finish typing the formula text, press ctrl+shift+enter on your keyboard to confirm the formula

Comment: Okay it looks like the first curly brace needs to go outside the `=`.  But awesome.  By the way I got this to work in Google Sheets by encapsulating the formula without curly braces with `ARRAYFORMULA()`

Comment: As far as I know, Google Sheets as an ARRAYFORMULA function. It's not the same syntax, but should be the same idea...